# Why am I getting a syntax error with this CMD script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, command-prompt

I'm trying to write a simple CMD script to automate the build of my repo. Here is the script in its entirety:

```
@echo off
setlocal

goto main

:: Functions

:buildSubdir

pushd %1
for /f %%projectFile in ('dir /b /s project.json') do (
    dnu restore "%%projectFile"
    dnu build "%%projectFile"
    dnu pack "%%projectFile"
)
popd
goto :EOF

:main

:: Check for dnu
where dnu > NUL 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    echo dnu wasn't found in your PATH! 1>&2
    echo See http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html for instructions on installing the DNX toolchain on your PC. 1>&2
    exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
)

:: Do the actual work
cd %~dp0
call :buildSubdir src
call :buildSubdir test
```

Basically, what it does is try to find all the files named `project.json` in a few select directories (`src` and `test`), and execute `dnu restore`, `dnu build`, and `dnu pack` on them.

For some reason, I seem to be getting a syntax error on the line where I enter a `for /f` loop, saying something about `%projectFile` not being recognized. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1892bd33f696e272b886) a gist of the full output from my terminal when I remove the `@echo off` statement and re-run the script.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and what I can do to fix it? Thanks.

---

**edit:** Just changed it to this:

```
for /f %%p in ('dir /b /s project.json') do (
    set projectFile=%%p
    dnu restore "%projectFile%"
    dnu build "%projectFile%"
    dnu pack "%projectFile%"
)
```

Still doesn't seem to be working, although the error messages are different now. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/d9f3cc734a847962a161) a gist of the new output. (Note how `%projectFile%` is set to the empty string.)

Comment: Variables in batch files are surrounded with `%`, so it would be `%projectFile%`. You're also referencing it in a `for` loop, so you'll need to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Comment: @KenWhite Not in `for /f` loops...

Comment: In `for` loops, they're referenced with `!`, as `!projectFile!`. I was editing my comment. :-) You also need to enable delayed expansion.

Comment: inf for loops tokens need to be a single symbol.

Comment: For future reference, saying things like *saying something about %projectfile not being recognized* and *still doesn't seem to be working, although the error messages are different* are not meaningful problem descriptions. You have the **specific, exact** error messages on your screen, right in front of your face, and you can copy/paste from a command window. Being too lazy to do so is not reasonable; you're asking for **free help** solving **your problem**, and you should make the effort to provide the details that are readily available to you in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%p in ('dir /b /s /a-d project.json') do (
    dnu restore "%%p"
    dnu build "%%p"
    dnu pack "%%p"
)
```

The directory name is assigned to `%%p` so since that's all you're using, you have no need to assign it further.

The `delims=` ensures that the entire line is assigned to `%%p` - otherwise, `%%p` will be assigned the first token using the default delimiter set, the practical outcome of which is to truncate the name at the first space.

See

```
for /?
```

from the prompt for docco.

The `/a-d` removes any directorynames from the `dir` output (just in case there is a directory name matching the mask supplied - small possibility though that might be)

If you'd wanted to manipulate the name in `%%p` rather than just use it as-is, you'd have needed to use either `delayedexpansion` or called another routine to do the manipulation. `The basis of this characteristic is the`delayedexpansion trap`- batch will substitute the *parse-time* value of any`%var%`it finds in a code-block (parenthesised series of statements) for`%var% before executing, so since `%projectFile%` was undefined at the start of the `for` loop, batch will replace it with *nothing* which is its value at that time.

For documentation, see many, many articles here related to `delayedexpansion` or read the scant documentation in

```
set /?
```

Comment: Awesome answer, you've addressed all of the points I had in my question (and then some). I have just one question though, does it make a difference here whether `delims=` is quoted or not?

Comment: @JamesKo : The "official syntax" is that the modifiers are quoted - see `for /?` from the prompt. There *are* circumstances where syntax quirks are exploited so that it's possible to *not* quote the modifiers - but I've never needed to use them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Magoo. :D

Answer (score 0):

With the For construct, you use letters as variables: a-z and A-Z (it is important to note that the letters are case-sensitive) in the For construct.  There are a number of ways you can use FOR and I would start here - http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

You can also `FOR /?` to get help as needed.

I think you are looking for this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

goto main

:: Functions

:buildSubdir

pushd %1
for /f %%p in ('dir /b /s project.json') do (
    dnu restore "%%p"
    dnu build "%%p"
    dnu pack "%%p"
)
popd
goto :EOF

:main

:: Check for dnu
where dnu > NUL 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    echo dnu wasn't found in your PATH! 1>&2
    echo See http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html for instructions on installing the DNX toolchain on your PC. 1>&2
    exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
)

:: Do the actual work
cd %~dp0
call :buildSubdir src
call :buildSubdir test
```

Comment: Needs a better explanation... you're the one who's answering the question. :(

Comment: @JamesKo - I have updated and cleaned up my response so hopefully it makes more sense.